# Irreducible representations of compact groups

Tags: representation-theory

I am trying to understand to what extend invariant theory of compact groups is not too different from the finite group case. Suppose I have a compact group $G$ acting on a finite dimensional vector space. Then, all irreducible representations that occur in an isotypic decomposition are finite dimensional. I want to understand how to construct them and thus I wonder if it is possible to always get a basis of such an irreducible representation that consists of elements that are invariant by a subgroup $G'$ of finite order.